# can i send variable from action to another action by request post?

Tags: php, post, yii, import, action

I called my action from other controller by this code:

```
Yii::import('application.controllers.ProvinceCityController');
$obj =new ProvinceCityController($id); // preparing object
echo $obj->actiondynamiccities(20);
```

Can I send my data(20) by post request ? Because `actiondynamiccities()` get `$_POST` and do something...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send a POST variable to a controller you can only do it by using AJAX.

If you want, you can send it by GET with a key to protect its security

```
 Yii::import('application.controllers.ProvinceCityController');
  $obj =new ProvinceCityController($id); // preparing object
  echo $obj->actiondynamiccities(20, /*SECRET*/);
```

And in the ProvinceCityController

```
public function actionDynamicCities($id = null,  $key = null)
{
   $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : $id;

   if(!isset($_POST['id'] && strcmp($key, /*SECRET*/) != 0)
   { throw Exception here... }

  ...continue with code
}
```

Also, think of getting this kind of secret even for POST ids.

Answer (score 0):

When a function is useful in multiple times across the multiple controllers, you have to maintain a separate class which can supply this functionality vai it's methods.

**Ex:** Create a class `SharedFuncs` and keep that file in `components` folder

```
<?php
    class SharedFuncs 
    {
        public function hello($name) {
            return "Helloo..!, ".ucfirst($name);
        }
    }
?>
```

And access the methods any where in your project.

```
<?php
    $utils=new SharedFuncs();
    echo $utils->hello('maryam');
?>
```